# Free allocated pointer passed to a function?

Tags: c++, pointers

When shall I free my unsigned char* if I need to pass the unsigned char* into a function?
Example

```
void myFunction(unsigned char *request){
   // do I need to use free(request); here?
}  

 int main (){       
 // main code 

 unsigned char *request = NULL;
 // read from buffer and reallocate memory (using realloc & memcpy)
 myFunction(request); // I do not want to read or use "request" after this function call. 
 free(request); // is this ok? Or should this be inside myFunction also?

 return 0; 
 }
```

Comment: You should free it when it's no longer useful/meaningful to any part of your code. But you shouldn't manually manage memory in the first place, there are better ways in C++. Your example looks like C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `free()` on something as soon as you're done using it. So for instance, you probably wouldn't do it inside `myFunction()` because you're probably still going to be interested in the value pointed at by `request` when you exit that function back to `main`.

Comment: So, Regardless if I don´t use passing by reference then it is safe to just have a    free(request) in the main function? I recall if you don´t use reference (as I don´t in the example) then a copy of the pointer is passed to the function, no? Anyway I´ll add a check for null before using free.

Comment: Actually you don't really need to invoke `free()` in your example, since you never use `malloc()` or anything else to reserve memory space. The purpose of `free()` is to free up space in memory that has been set aside for other purposes but which is no longer being used.

Comment: Well... I didn´t post that part. the first comment was a pseudocode for when I am reading data into the unsigned char* from a buffer. As I read one byte at a time I use realloc followed by memcpy to get the data into the unsigned char*. I do not use malloc though.

Comment: That's fine. Just use `free()` once all your work with `request` or whatever other pointer you're using is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have to free it where you have allocated it, and don't need more it.
In This case you can do it in both places, but also, after freed set it to NULL, and next time when you'll try to free it, check for null

also you mai implement something like:

```
void FreeAndNull(void *request){
   if request <> NULL then 
     { free(request); request = NULL; }
}
```

Comment: setting a parameter to NULL at function exit won't do a thing; you'd need a reference parameter

Comment: @Kos, thanks... 
I thought in Delphi terms (FreeAndNil methos)... 
Anyway, I think it is possible ti implement such safe `free` in C++ too, using the same logic.

Comment: Yes, `void *&request` will make a parameter that is a reference to a pointer to void` so that you can implement this. Also the `!=` check is redundant in C++, as `delete` or `free` is a no-op is the value is null already.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do this - but a good practice is to free things at the same level as you allocated them. E.g. don't allocate something in a function and free it after it is returned. Because then the lifecycle of the memory is not clear to you months later when you look at the code again.

So it is much better to:

```
request = malloc();
doStuff( request );
free( request );
```

than the pattern you have. C++ helps you with this pattern by creating constructors and destructors. That is a constructor may actually allocate memory and essentially return it to you in the form of an object, but the compiler will automatically call the destructor for you freeing the memory.

So you can achieve something like the pattern you want with a much safer and more maintainable pattern if you wrap that request buffer in a class:

```
Request::Request() { mRequest = malloc(); }
Request::~Request() { if ( mRequest ) free( mRequest ); mRequest = NULL; }

...

{
    Request request;
    myFunction( request );
}
```

With this pattern you memory is cleaned up automatically. Safer and more maintainable.